# Multiplying two separate dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I would like to use them to create a third by applying a simple function. The datasets are quite large so instead of looping through every row and column, is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
# dfA
id   | value |
mars | 10    |
jupt | 15    |
satn | 14    |


# dfB
id   | A   | B   | C   |
satn | 0.5 | 0.3 | 0.2 |
mars | 0.2 | 0.5 | 0.3 |
jupt | 0.6 | 0.3 | 0.1 |
```

End result should be a multiplication of `dfA` by the corresponding `id` in `dfB`

```
# dfResult
id   | A      | B      | C      |
mars | 10*0.2 | 10*0.5 | 10*0.3 |
jupt | 15*0.5 | 15*0.3 | 15*0.1 |
satn | 14*0.5 | 14*0.3 | 14*0.2 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for match, multiple by [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and last create column from `index`:

```
df = dfB.set_index('id').mul(dfA.set_index('id')['value'], axis=0).reset_index()
print (df)
     id    A    B    C
0  jupt  9.0  4.5  1.5
1  mars  2.0  5.0  3.0
2  satn  7.0  4.2  2.8
```